# Block Diagonal Matrices Misunderstanding (Representation Theory)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, representation-theory

So, I was watching this video on an introduction to representation theory https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rDzaKASMTM&t=525s   and I'm good all the way up to between 8:20 to 8:35 when he mentions Block diagonal form. Could someone please help me clear up my understanding of this because I get very lost at this point, even though I have tried reading about block diagonal matrices online. Here is what I understand. Let

$$\pi_1(g)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\
                                         0 & 0 & 1\\
                                         1 & 0 & 0\\
                                         \end{pmatrix}$$ 
where $g$ is the cycle $(132)$ and $\pi_1$ a representation of $S_3$ to $\mathbb{C}^3$, which has eigenvalues $l_1=1$,$l_2=-(1/2)-(\sqrt{3}/2)i$,$l_3=-(1/2)+(\sqrt{3}/2)i$. Now, I write $\mathbb{C}^3$ as the direct sum of the invariant spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ where $V_1$ is the span of \begin{pmatrix}1\\
                                                       1\\  
                                                       1\\
                                                       \end{pmatrix} 
and $V_2$ is all matrices \begin{pmatrix}a\\
                                                       b\\  
                                                       c\\
                                                       \end{pmatrix} 
such that $a+b+c=0$ (Note $V_2$ has dimension 2).

Then, if we choose a basis B (based off the invariant subspaces) for $\mathbb{C}^3$, $b_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\
                                                       1\\  
                                                       1\\
                                                       \end{pmatrix}$ 
                                    $b_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
                                                   1\\  
                                                   -1\\
                                                   \end{pmatrix}$ 
                                    $b_3=\begin{pmatrix}1\\
                                                   0\\  
                                                   -1\\
                                                   \end{pmatrix}$,

I understand that $[\pi_1(g)]_B$ should have a 1 in the the top right 1x1 partition of the matrix (there is a 2x2 partition in the bottom right) and I understand why there are zeroes everywhere not on the diagonal of the block form of the matrix, however, I don't understand how to compute the bottom  2x2 block matrix. According to http://www.wright.edu/~chaocheng.huang/lecture/mth255/mth255lect13.pdf   the bottom right-hand corner 2x2 block matrix should be,

\begin{pmatrix}
                                     -1/2 & -\sqrt{3}/2\\
                                     \sqrt{3}/2 & -1/2\\
                                     \end{pmatrix}
so you get, \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
                                     0 & -1/2 & -\sqrt{3}/2\\
                                     0 & \sqrt{3}/2 & -1/2\\
                                     \end{pmatrix}

however, here is where I get stuck:

Under $\pi_1(g)$, the basis vector $b_2$ should be sent to \begin{pmatrix}1\\
                                                   -1\\  
                                                   0\\
                                                   \end{pmatrix} 
however, according to our block diagonal matrix, $$0\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$ should equal $\begin{pmatrix}1\\
                                                   -1\\  
                                                   0\\
                                                   \end{pmatrix}$ 
however, it does not equal this, it instead equals,

$$\begin{pmatrix}
                                                   -\sqrt{3}/2\\  
                                                   -1/2\\
                                                   1+\sqrt{3}/2\\
                                                   \end{pmatrix} 
$$
So where have I gone wrong, where is my misunderstanding?

Thanks so much if you got to the bottom of this (a lot of reading!), and I would really appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: @m_t_ the calculation is $\pi_1(g)(b_2)$ not $b_1$. And thank you for correcting right not left that is indeed what I meant. Similar to what matrix?

Comment: @m_t_ Could you explain the video from 8:20-8:35?

Comment: @m_t_ Sorry you are right, I will change that now. Still, even when correct, it still does not equal \begin{matrix}
                                                   -\sqrt{3}/2\\  
                                                   -1/2\\
                                                   (1+\sqrt{3}/2)\\
                                                   \end{matrix}

Comment: Like I said, the notes say that the bottom right block is *similar* to the matrix you wrote down, not equal to it.

Comment: @m_t_ Okay thank you. Could you please explain the video from 8:20 to 8:35 for me then because I can't seem to make sense of it?

Comment: Can someone just please explain the video 8:20 to 8:35 - thats what Im confused on the msot